# TypeError: result.slice is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am trying to run multiple mongodb queries using node/mongoose. I have very similar code working in the same file but not the same route. The differences are the queries (same format just different search params) and the `res.render` line.

I have done about an hour of googling and searching stack overflow and so far found nothing helpful.

**Error message**

```
TypeError: result.slice is not a function
    at results.map.result (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sailhr/server/routes/hr.js:73:58)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Promise.all.then.results (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sailhr/server/routes/hr.js:73:36)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

**Code**

```
let queries = [
        User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser){
           if(err){
               req.flash('error', 'Could not find the user requested.');
           }
        }),
        User.find({companyID: req.user.companyID, role: "manager" }, function(err, allManagers){
           if(err){
               req.flash('error', 'Could not find all company managers.');
           }
        })
        ];
        Promise.all(queries)
            .then(results => (results.map(result => (result.slice(1)))))
            .then(adaptedResults => res.render('user/profileEdit', {header: 'EDIT USER PROFILE', Employee: adaptedResults[0], managers: adaptedResults[1]}))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                req.flash('error', err[0]);
                res.redirect('/users');
            });
```

Comment: Base on the error, one of your query is not returning an array. `findById` maybe?

Comment: @Jalil Thank you, that fixed it I switched from `findById` to just `find` and used a `_id` query. Mind saying how you knew it was an array issue?

Comment: In your code, you call result.slice(), in the error it says that slice is not a function. It means is that result doesn't have `slice()` method. I know that it work only on array and string. I know also that `find` will return an array. So I guess its the findById. That is why I just leave a comment and not an answer because I am not also entirely sure.

Comment: @Jalil Thanks for the explanation, I had thought it worked but guess not so much now. Now it returns an array of empty arrays. So what my view is actually looking for is an object not an array which is part of my issue. As for the second query, it is returning a blank array but that is expected with my current data set though there might be issues with how I have done it.